# Cannot get LaTeX working in Amazon SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am running python notebooks in SageMaker, however, the notebooks need LaTeX to be available. How would I go about installing LaTeX on a SageMaker notebook instance? For more info, this is the error that python produces;

```
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

Thanks for the help!

I tried running the [on-start script from the official aws-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/export-to-pdf-enable/on-start.sh) which should enable LaTeX (originally for pdf export but should serve this purpose). However, on trying to start the notebook kernel I get this error (some info replaced with `<->`;

```
Failed to start kernel due to start-up script failure

Failed to launch app [pytorch-1-1-ml-g4dn-xl-latex-on-st-<->]. ConfigurationError: LifecycleConfig execution failed with non zero exit code 127 for script arn:aws:sagemaker:<>:studio-lifecycle-config/latex-on-start. Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-lcc-debug.html for debugging instructions. (Context: RequestId: c7d9252d-09d9-4eff-845b-69c150898e10, TimeStamp: 1674399729.767251, Date: Sun Jan 22 15:02:09 2023)

No failed app was found
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error when provisioning a LCC through the AWS Web Console.

It turns out that **when you write your script within the web console, it doesn't automatically encode your script as base64** - a requirement for all LCCs.

I don't know if you received the same error for the same reason - it seems rather generic - but this worked for me. More details mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-lcc-create-cli.html

1. Write your script on a system with AWS CLI and necessary sagemaker IAM permissions and save it (example: `my-script.sh`)
2. Save a transformation of your script to a base64-encoded version to an environment variable via:

```
LCC_CONTENT=`openssl base64 -A -in my-script.sh`
```

3. Create your LCC (via AWS CLI) using the following command, passing in your environment variable (`$LCC_CONTENT`) and specifying the correct `region` and desired `lifecycle-config-name`:

```
aws sagemaker create-studio-lifecycle-config \
--region region \
--studio-lifecycle-config-name my-lcc \
--studio-lifecycle-config-content $LCC_CONTENT \
--studio-lifecycle-config-app-type KernelGateway
```

4. Then re-attach the LCC to your sagemaker domain and try agian.